# How to include a generated api gateway sdk in a typescript nodejs project

Tags: typescript, aws-api-gateway

I have created an API Gateway API and I want to use it from a nodejs project which I am writing in typescript. For this, I want to include the generated SDK.

The generated SDK consists of js files which do not export anything. For example the main file "apigClient" basically looks like this:

```
var apigClientFactory = {};
apigClientFactory.newClient = function (config) {
...
}
```

To use this in a javascript project, one would have to do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="apigClient.js"></script>
```

How do I do the same thing in a nodejs project written in typescript?

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same issue.

The SDK is not suitable for Node. In order to use the SDK on Node, you would have to change the code to be modular.

I found a library that allowed me to communicate with API Gateway through Node: `aws-api-gateway-client`.

NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-api-gateway-client
Repository: https://github.com/kndt84/aws-api-gateway-client

However with this library, you will have to implement the requests by yourself. Adapted from there README:

```js
// Require module
var apigClientFactory = require('aws-api-gateway-client').default;
// ES6:
// import apigClientFactory from 'aws-api-gateway-client';
// Set invokeUrl to config and create a client.
// For authorization, additional information is 
// required as explained below.

// you can find the following url on 
// AWS Console/Gateway in the API Gateway Stage session
config = {invokeUrl:'https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com}
var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient(config);

// Calls to an API take the form outlined below. 
// Each API call returns a promise, that invokes 
// either a success and failure callback

var params = {
    //This is where any header, path, or querystring 
    // request params go. The key is the parameter 
    // named as defined in the API
    userId: '1234',
};
// Template syntax follows url-template
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-template
var pathTemplate = '/users/{userID}/profile'
var method = 'GET';
var additionalParams = {
    //If there are any unmodeled query parameters
    // or headers that need to be sent with the request
    // you can add them here
    headers: {
        param0: '',
        param1: ''
    },
    queryParams: {
        param0: '',
        param1: ''
    }
};
var body = {
    //This is where you define the body of the request
};

apigClient.invokeApi(params, pathTemplate, method, additionalParams, body)
    .then(function(result){
        //This is where you would put a success callback
    }).catch( function(result){
        //This is where you would put an error callback
    });
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for sharing your implementation, much appreciated!

Can I ask a question though and please see here for more details https://github.com/kndt84/aws-api-gateway-client/issues/58

Essentially I'm new to AWS and have looked into AWS MobileHub but I'd rather implement the services independently. I'm currently using the `aws-api-gateway-client` which works great but I'm a bit confused to the approach of interfacing both a react native app and react js dashboard to API Gateway.

Additionally how do you go about initialising `aws-api-gateway-client` for the entire react native app?

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm happy to know that I helped you. Regarding MobileHub, I cannot answer your question since I'm not familiar with it. I hope someone will give you an insightful question on the ticket you opened on GitHub.

Now, in order to initialize the `api-gateway-client` for the entire app, if you create a Module, in which you instantiate the object, and then, export it, you'll be able to use it as a single instance everywhere in your app. Since JavaScript Modules are Singletons, it should be straightforward. See a simple example here: https://jsfiddle.net/qs2p75nu/6/

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to import this into my typescript project running static website on s3:

"import apigClientFactory from 'aws-api-gateway-client';"

gives me error:

TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'aws-api-gateway-client'. '/node_modules/aws-api-gateway-client/dist/apigClient.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.